# Lightning: setCallback() method is not been called, and no Error message is returned

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-community, javascript-controller

Updated:

Apex Code:

```
 public class MyAccountsController {

@auraEnabled
 public Static List<Account> getAccounts(Id accountID){
    List<Account> accountList = [Select Id,Name,Account_text__c, 
          AccountNumber,Website,Type,Industry,AnnualRevenue,Rating 
          FROM Account WHere id =: accountID];
    return accountList;
}


@auraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> saveAccount(List<Account> accountList1){

    Map<String,String> resultMap = new Map<String,String>();
    try{
        system.debug('saveAccount:'+accountList1);
        update accountList1;
        resultMap.put('status','success');
        resultMap.put('message','Data saved successfully');
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        resultMap.put('status','error');
        resultMap.put('message',e.getMessage());           
    }
    return resultMap;
 }
```

}

The Apex method is not been called. I check debug statements and also Console logs.

Controller:

```
({
  saveAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
    var btn = event.getSource();
    var name = btn.get('v.name');
    if(name=='save'){
        helper.saveAccounts(component, event, helper); 
    }
  }
})
```

Helper:

In helper class the saveAccount method is been called and im setting the Params. 
After that the setCallbck() method is not been called.
I could see till the console log before the callback function. Is it because im using the setCallback twice in the process.??

```
 ({
    fetchAccounts : function(component, event, helper) 
      {


        var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
        var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
        //var toastEvent = $A.get('e.force:showToast');
        action.setParams({
            accountID : accountId
         });

        Console.log('test');         // I could see upto this
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();


        if(state ==='SUCCESS'){
            var accountList = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.accountList",accountList);
        }
        else{
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

saveAccounts : function(component, event, helper){
    var accountList = component.get("v.accountList");
    console.log(accountList);
    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveAccount");
    var toastEvent = $A.get('e.force:showToast');
    saveAction.setParams({              
        accountList : accountList 
    });

    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(response){  // Not working
        var state = response.getState();
        var btn = event.getSource();
        console.log('test');
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            console.log('test Success');
            var dataMap=response.getReturnValue();
            if(dataMap.status == 'success'){
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title' : 'Success!',
                    'type' : 'success',
                    'mode' : 'dismissable',
                    'message' : dataMap.message
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
            else if(dataMap.status =='error'){
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title' : 'Error!',
                    'type' : 'error',
                    'mode' : 'dismissable',
                    'message' : dataMap.message
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
      });
      console.log('last');    // I can see this log.
      $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
    }
 })
```

Comment: did you check apex debug logs whether apex method getting called or not?

Comment: `setCallback()`  function use is to execute after the queue of actions returns ,so only you seeing last console log. Can you edit a question with apex class method so its easy to debug might be you missing something there.

Comment: please add backend code in the question or probably component code too, It will give the full picture

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with the way you have defined your helper method. For the method `fetchAccounts` you have passed in the arguments as`(component, event, helper)` to which  I believe that you should not pass the parameter helper. Please make the changes to `(component, event)` in the method definition and from where the method is being called i.e. your controller.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that returned javascript object from the server has a status variable and the values for it must be "success" or "error" case sensitive.

If your response does not contain a status variable with "success" or "error" then toast is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Server params should be called with the exact same names from server to client so you need the apex method definition to have the param name `accountList` (without the `1`):

`public static Map<String,String> saveAccount(List<Account> accountList1){`

Then you can set your param on your client with the exact same name:

```
saveAction.setParams({              
    accountList : accountList 
});
```

As long as the param type is the same (you have defined the type in your markup which you have not shared with us), This should work

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and it worked, but don't know the reason.

Changed Apex method name from `"saveAccount : function(component, event, helper)"` to   `"saveAccount1 : function(component, event, helper)"`.

Also changed the variable name of   `"var saveAction = component.get("c.saveAccount");"` to  `"var saveAction1 = component.get("c.saveAccount1");"`

I think this is because the naming may have problem with some standard names.